# GUI apps using Qt seg-fault, think wrong path is being checked?

Tags: ubuntu, gnome, wayland, qt

I cannot open any of my Ubuntu 22.04 apps which use the Qt library (Konsole, P4V, Wireshark etc). They immediately seg-fault.

When I start Konsole with debug logging I can see it's trying to find metadata searching for libraries in path `/usr/lib/plugins/platforms`:

```
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() checking directory path "/usr/lib/plugins/platforms" ...
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() looking at "/usr/lib/plugins/platforms/libqminimal.so"
"Failed to extract plugin meta data from '/usr/lib/plugins/platforms/libqminimal.so'" 
         not a plugin
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() looking at "/usr/lib/plugins/platforms/libqoffscreen.so"
"Failed to extract plugin meta data from '/usr/lib/plugins/platforms/libqoffscreen.so'" 
         not a plugin
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() looking at "/usr/lib/plugins/platforms/libqvkkhrdisplay.so"
"Failed to extract plugin meta data from '/usr/lib/plugins/platforms/libqvkkhrdisplay.so'" 
         not a plugin
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() looking at "/usr/lib/plugins/platforms/libqvnc.so"
"Failed to extract plugin meta data from '/usr/lib/plugins/platforms/libqvnc.so'" 
         not a plugin
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() looking at "/usr/lib/plugins/platforms/libqxcb.so"
"Failed to extract plugin meta data from '/usr/lib/plugins/platforms/libqxcb.so'" 
         not a plugin
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() checking directory path "/usr/bin/platforms" ...
qt.qpa.plugin: Could not find the Qt platform plugin "wayland" in ""
This application failed to start because no Qt platform plugin could be initialized. Reinstalling the application may fix this problem.
```

When I run Konsole on a working system it loads the libraries from a different path:

```
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() checking directory path "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/plugins/platforms" ...
Found metadata in lib /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/plugins/platforms/libqminimal.so
```

Is this the problem/how do I fix this?

**UPDATE:**

It seems my QT_PLUGIN_PATH is pointing to the wrong value. It's pointing at `/usr/lib/plugins/platforms` when it should be `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/plugins/`.

When I export this to the correct value Konsole works.

I've never explicitly changed this. Is there a way to reset the Qt installation? I don't do Qt development, just need it for my GUI apps.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are running Wayland without `qt5-wayland` or `qt6-wayland` installed. Install them may solve you problem.

You can switch to xorg to solve this too, but I don't recommend to do this.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I've added an update with what I discovered. During my initial panic I did try `sudo apt-get install --reinstall qtwayland5` but it didn't solve the problem. Is there a way to reinstall Qt from scratch? Worryingly I did try reinstalling every `apt` package using `sudo apt reinstall '~i'` but that didn't work either.